# SSRS error when running the report in reporting server

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Can anyone please tell me what this error is[image]

After running the report for long time, I got the above error in reporting server. 
We have also increased the space in the Reporting server.

When I run the stored procedure of the report in SSMS it took just 33 seconds. Can I know how to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the "time out".

 **Steps to achieve this method:**

1. Enter to data sets folder.
2. Choose your data set.
3. Go to the "Time out" field and increase the value.

[image]

for more documentation [Setting Time-out Values for Report and Shared Dataset Processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/setting-time-out-values-for-report-and-shared-dataset-processing-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Hi Benzi, I tried adding 30 and 60 different Time out seconds, I still see the same error.

Comment: Hi Benzi, I have put some max number 999999 and the report loaded quickly on my local machine but this is not working on the report server. I changed under the properties on the server. I still get the same error. Can I know what could be the problem.